# Unable to connect to Dedicated Bedrock Server from the same PC

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

I have a Dedicated Bedrock Server running on my PC, and I can't connect from the same PC where the server is. If I add it onto the list of servers, it appears as "Locating server" and never finds it.

[image]

If I try to connect, I get "Unable to connect to world".

[image]

On my friend's PS4, it appears on the Friends tab as a LAN Game on a Dedicated Server.

[image]

And also on my sister's laptop.

[image]

Comment: Well try checking your internet

Comment: Hi @Caden. Lemon is trying to connect directly to a server running on the same PC. Internet connectivity shouldn't matter in this case.

Comment: I had the same problem 'unable to connect to world' when 2 players connect from the same router/ip. Solution for me was let 1 player use a VPN, and the problem was solved. Tried is with pc <-> pc and android <-> pc,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file `bedrock_server_how_to.html` in the same compressed file as the server contains some information:

> On some systems, when you wish to connect to the server using a client running on the same machine as the server is running on, you will need to exempt the Minecraft client from UWP loopback restrictions:
>
> ```
> CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt –a
> –p=S-1-15-2-1958404141-86561845-1752920682-3514627264-368642714-62675701-733520436
> ```

You just need to copy and paste that command on a cmd terminal as administrator to lift the restrictions.